# How to import hdbscan on Jupyter Python 3?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed hdbscan using `conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan`, in Linux os. The `import hdbscan` works from the command line of python, but not on notebooks Jupyter. It also works from Pyhon2.7 of Jupyter but not on Python 3.

```
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hdbscan'
```

Comment: Every python interpreter has its own set of packages. Every jupyter kernel is installed into one interpreter. You have to make sure that (a) you installed hdbscan into all interpreters you want to use (e.g. python 2.7 and python 3.7) and (b) that the kernels you use in jupyter are based on an interpreter you installed hdbscan into.

Answer (score 1):

How to install jupyter and get environments as Jupiter kernels:

1. Start Command Promt (CMD) as administrator (right click). Do not enter any environment yet.
2. Install Jupyter (and nb_conda as well as ipykernel) to get your environments listed: conda install jupyter nb_conda ipykernel
3. Activate the environment you want to add to jupyter kernel: conda activate myenv
4. Install ipykernel in the environment (do this for all envvironemnts you would like to add): conda install ipykernel
5. To start Jupyter, cd to root (cd .. until you are at C:) then type (does not need to be inside and env): Jupyter noteboook
6. You might need to confirm that it shall open in a web browser (I use chrome) Once open in a browser navigate to the folder of your choice, then make a new python 3 file.
7. Once inside click Kernel -> Change kernel and select the conda env you would like

You should now be able to change kernel (env) within all conda environments that have ipykernel installed (step 4)